# Flutter: Future<String> returns null but if printing it has value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

username is null but if I'm printing 'value' it contains some string, how can I get 'value'?

```
class HomeWrapper extends StatelessWidget {

  final DataBaseServices _db = DataBaseServices();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    String username;
    _db.getUsername(user).then((value) => username = value);
    print(username);

    if(username != null){
      return Home();
    }else{
      _db.createBlankUser(user);
      return EditProfile();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` is called when the value of the `Future` is returned. So the value of `value` is always non null, whereas `username` is null when you print it.

Try the difference by replacing `.then(...)` with:

```
.then((value){
  username = value;
  print(username);
});
```

Additionally, you can have a look at how to [handle Asynchronous data in Flutter](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `_db.getUsername` is returning a Future?
In that case you should look into using `FutureBuilder`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```dart
return FutureBuilder(
    builder: (context, snap) {
    //snap.data will be the username
      if(snap.hasData) {
        return Home();
      } else {
        //you need to wait for another Future here I guess?
        return FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snap2){
            if(snap2.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
              return EditProfile();
            } else {
             //return some sort of circular loader icon.
            }
          },
          future: _db.createBlankUser(user)
        );
      }
    },
    future: _db.getUsername(user),
  );
```